# Openedx devstack installation

Tags: docker, devstack, openedx

[Instructions of openedx devstack installation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVad6.png)

I'm trying to install the openedx hawthorn release on my Mac. I followed the instructions, but when I ran `make dev.clone`, it gave me the error below:

fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

make: *** [Makefile:41: dev.clone] Error 128

[My command line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aFMWG.png)

Any suggestions on how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Please follow this instructions/guide. It works fine.
https://github.com/edx/devstack#open-edx-devstack-

Answer (score 8):

after step 2,

edit the repo.sh file on line 93 like this:

`cd $name
 git checkout open-release/${OPENEDX_RELEASE}
 cd ..`

You need to add 1 & 3 line. And then follow further steps.

Answer (score 3):

you can try the below command

```
make dev.clone.https
```

When you try to `make dev.clone` by default it uses ssh to clone the repository. In windows using ssh for git clone gives the error. So try using https for git clone.

Comment: The error also occurs when using ssh in WSL2.